# Can't connect to local SQL Server using windows container, but can using Linux container

Tags: sql-server, docker, networking, dns, windows-container

I'm trying to just have a basic connection with a SQL Server (not in a container) that is running on my local dev machine (Windows 11) and connect to it using a windows container.

I keep getting an error similar to this:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)

And here is the Dockerfile (for one of the applications that isn't working). This was generated by Visual Studio:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["EmailTestDocker/EmailTestDocker.csproj", "EmailTestDocker/"]
RUN dotnet restore "EmailTestDocker/EmailTestDocker.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/EmailTestDocker"
RUN dotnet build "EmailTestDocker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "EmailTestDocker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "EmailTestDocker.dll"]
```

I've tried initially connecting with a C# .NET Core console app. If I run this without the Docker container using this connection string it does work and I get data

```
Connection String: "Server=tcp:(computer name or localhost),1433;Initial Catalog=(db name);Persist Security Info=False;User ID=(user);Password= password);MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;"
```

I can also run that in a linux container and get data, except I need to use either the computer name or host.docker.internal for the server name. If I run it in a windows container nothing works.

I've also tried using a python app with the same results.

My guess is that the windows container can't connect to the SQL Server 1433 port due to some firewall or network issue.

I've also reproduced this issue on another windows laptop, so it's not just this dev machine.

When I do an interactive PowerShell console with the container and run some different commands here are the results:

```
Resolve-DnsName host.docker.internal

Resolve-DnsName : host.docker.internal : DNS name does not exist ... (more to this error)


Resolve-DnsName (computer name)

(computer name).local    AAAA   60    Answer     fe80::dc77:c5a9:10f9:b3a
(computer name).local                            A      60    Answer     172.25.80.1


Test-NetConnection -ComputerName (computer name) -Port 1433
```

> WARNING: TCP connect to (fe80::dc77:c5a9:10f9:b3a%4 : 1433) failed
> WARNING: TCP connect to (172.25.80.1 : 1433) failed
> ComputerName           : (computer name)
> RemoteAddress          : fe80::dc77:c5a9:10f9:b3a%4
> RemotePort             : 1433
> InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet
> SourceAddress          : fe80::a94f:9732:c448:9692%4
> PingSucceeded          : True
> PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms
> TcpTestSucceeded       : False

```
docker network inspect nat (silly_poincare is the container name)

[
    {
        "Name": "nat",
        "Id": "c1eb0498ed676f5b3bebf3a3359cc769599f2395b20ffdf19b73f6bbb55cb8d5",
        "Created": "2023-08-27T13:58:49.6748484-05:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "nat",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "windows",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.25.80.0/20",
                    "Gateway": "172.25.80.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "c0b7c2914187f819659142a2daf3987ec9c1c91abb82e949870d0441ccc77c1f": {
                "Name": "silly_poincare",
                "EndpointID": "84651f3c036d038e96047a8836fdf4f486dbec945d0c1ccff2f5cc4aa55edd42",
                "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:5c:d4:c0",
                "IPv4Address": "172.25.94.69/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.windowsshim.hnsid": "(guid)",
            "com.docker.network.windowsshim.networkname": "nat"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Also it does look like I'm using hyper V although I don't think I'm using Hyper-V containers

*Update 8/29/2023
I'm now wondering if this is a sql server issue. I tried using SSMS to connect to the sql server on my dev machine from another machine on my local network. I can ping the dev machine, but can't connect via SSMS (same error as above).

I ran [SQLCHECK](https://github.com/microsoft/CSS_SQL_Networking_Tools/wiki/SQLCHECK). There is a lot of data, but I am seeing a few things that might help:

> The following HOSTS file entries were found for this machine:
>
> ```
> 192.168.0.129 host.docker.internal
> 192.168.0.129 gateway.docker.internal
> 127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
> ```
>
> The following IP addresses are associated with this machine:
>
> ```
> Address Family  Address                     
> --------------  ----------------------------
> InterNetworkV6  fe80::f5b1:d691:6bd8:2d8a%12
> InterNetworkV6  fe80::64c2:f44e:925:574c%57 
> InterNetworkV6  fe80::ed65:3592:dec4:350b%39
> InterNetworkV6  fe80::3bba:af49:b8e:87d7%29 
> InterNetworkV6  fe80::dc77:c5a9:10f9:b3a%20 
> InterNetwork    192.168.0.129               
> InterNetwork    172.8.128.1                 
> InterNetwork    172.25.0.1                  
> InterNetwork    172.24.112.1                
> InterNetwork    172.25.80.1
> ```
>
> No SQL Aliases were found on this machine.

Comment: So is `172.25.80.1` the correct IP address for the SQL Server? It would seem to be an IP address managed by a Docker network.

Comment: I believe it's the IP of the host in the docker network. I'm not very knowledgeable about networking.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can connect to an external sql server running in Azure, so it's not that port 1433 is blocked completely or that there is an issue connecting to sql servers in general. It's specifically a locally hosted sql server

Comment: another thing I found out. if I create a SmtpClient in c# using host.docker.internal with port 1025 it does hit the MailHog smtp server I have running on the host. And when I ping host.docker.internal it shows the IP as 192.168.0.129. Also I tried just opening a TcpClient in c# to host.docker.internal with port 1433 and it refuses the connection

Comment: How did you create the Windows container? According to the CIDR notation the container thinks it's connected to a much larger network (`"IPv4Address": "172.25.94.69/16"` == 172.25.0.0-172.25.255.255) than the Docker network is configured to provide (`"Subnet": "172.25.80.0/20"` == 172.25.80.0-172.25.95.255). That could lead to traffic targeting addresses outside the 172.25.80.0-172.25.95.255 range *not* getting correctly routed out via the gateway address and so unable to communicate.

Comment: I've used both the built in Visual Studio container tools as well as doing a build myself "docker build -t emailtester:dev -f EmailTestDocker/Dockerfile ." and then I ran that and I get the same error. Also why is it just port 1433? port 1025 works, also I can reach out to an external API on port 443 (haven't tried a local api though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the windows firewall. I had the bright idea to just turn it off to see if that was it and bing the windows container could connect to my local sql server using either the hostname or the host.docker.internal. I looked up how to add the firewall exception

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "SQLServer default instance" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 1433 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "SQLServer Browser service" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 1434 -Protocol UDP -Action Allow
```

And then I turned the firewall back on and it still works. I got rid of MyPublic network from above and it still works with the default "nat" network that windows containers use by default (at least this version). Sorry if this was obvious to other people and I should have checked the firewall to begin with, but none of the tutorials mention this.
*It is important to note that you probably want to exclude Public networks, but I don't know much about firewalls.

Thanks to everyone who responded!

Answer (score 0):

By default Windows containers don´t have an interface, so you need to create it manually and attach to the container:

```
docker network create -d nat --gateway 172.8.128.1 --subnet 172.8.128.0/20 -o com.docker.network.windowsshim.dnsservers=4.4.4.4,8.8.8.8 -o com.docker.network.windowsshim.disable_gatewaydns=true MyPublic
docker network connect MyPublic MyContainer
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this doesn't make sense to me. I've never seen a windows container tutorial requiring creating a a network interface. Also what is the "nat" network interface which seems to be created and connected automatically? Also why does port 1025 for email work but 1433 for sql doesn't, but 1433 works for connecting to external sql servers? 
I did run the command you said to create the MyPublic network interface and connected it to my container. Now there are two network interfaces connected (MyPublic and nat), but it still can't connect to host.docker.internal on port 1433

Comment: don´t connect to host.docker.internal, just connect to your hostname on port 1433 (the one where SQL Server is running on)

Comment: I tried that and it isn't working. I'm wondering if it's actually an issue with the sql server. I added some info to the post

Comment: why don´t you create SQL Server in a container? this way you can rule out the firewall on your host, and you can connect to it from your host and from your containers, this may help: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7093/install-sql-server-install-oracle-powershell-windows-containers/